# Vb Write a program to print multiples of 2 and 3

Tags: vb.net

For my class, i need to write a program to find multiples of 2 and 3. The code i have would get me multiples of any number inputted into the program. My problem is that nothing is showing up in the message box that i've created and i don't know why. here's the code.

```
Public Class form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal Sender)
        Dim Number1 As Integer
        Dim Number2 As Integer
        Dim Multiplier As Integer
        Dim Answer As Integer
        Dim i As Integer
        Number1 = Val(TextBox1.Text)
        Number2 = Val(TextBox2.Text)
        Multiplier = 1
        Do While Multiplier <= 10
            For i = Number1 To Number2
                Answer = i * Multiplier
                ListBox1.Items.Add(i & "*" & Multiplier & "=" & Answer)
            Next i
            Multiplier = Multiplier + 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see any code that does anything with a message box. Do you mean the list box?

Comment: Your click handler is missing some information, like the EventArgs, and a handler.  In other words, your button isn't wired to run that code.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I'm using  a list box.

Comment: okay. If it isn't wired to the code, how would I do that? everything i try isn't working.

Comment: It should look something like this: `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but I think, this is what you looking for - all numbers that can be divided by 3 and 2 using multipliers from 1 to 10 over the range of numbers in your text boxes. In your code, I don't see where you weeding out your numbers that can be divided by 2 and 3

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender as Object, ByVal e as EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim num1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim num2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox2.Text)
    ' may be need to check num2 > num1

    Dim sum As Integer       
    For mult as Integer = 1 to 10
        For i as integer = num1 To num2
            total = i * mult
            If sum Mod 2 = 0 OrElse sum Mod 3 = 0 Then 
                ListBox1.Items.Add(i.ToString() & " * " & mult & " = " & sum.ToString())
            End If
        Next i

    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess as to what you are wanting. You said you were wanting multiples of 2 and 3 for any numbers given to the program, that that's what this does. If you wanted multiples of anything else, just add onto the part inside the `{}` in the coefficients declaration. Instead of using text boxes for input, I suggest using a `NumericUpDown`instead; the GUI will be more intuitive to the end user.

```vb
Imports System.Text
Public Class Form1


    Private Property maxNumb As Integer
    Private Property minNumb As Integer
    Private coefficients() As Integer = {2, 3}

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Button, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder
        For i = Me.minNumb To maxNumb Step 1
            For Each coef As Integer In coefficients
                sb.Append(i & " * ").Append(coef).Append(" = ").Append(i * coef)
                Me.ListBox1.Items.Add(sb.ToString)
                sb.Clear()
            Next
        Next
        Me.ListBox1.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(sender As NumericUpDown, e As EventArgs) Handles min_NumericUpDown1.ValueChanged, max_NumericUpDown2.ValueChanged
        If sender.Name.Contains("max") Then
            Me.maxNumb = sender.Value
        Else
            Me.minNumb = sender.Value
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```